# HIDL to AIDL HAL conversion

Tags: android, migration, aidl, hal, hidl

I have recently started working on Android side and end up with one issue.
As from Android U onwards all Android HALs will be migrated to AIDLs, I am currently trying to do this migration for my project. With the hidl2aidl tool I am successfully able to generate *.aidl files.

But I am observing the below fixme line in my generated aidl file.

**// FIXME: AIDL does not allow int to be an out parameter.
// Move it to return, or add it to a Parcelable.**

Is there any know fix for these kind of FixMes? Is there any issue in setting out parameter with AIDL? What if I have multiple out parameters from a function?

Comment: Adding comment for highlighting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I modified out int to out int[] and it worked. But wonder if this is the the proper solution.